# Loss of Power/Acceleration, RPM Flutter, Black Smoke - Ford Ranger PX 2015 3.2L

Tags: ford, leak, power, ranger, vacuum

First time using this site, so forgive me if I post incorrectly.

*BEING DETAILED AS POSSIBLE*

- I have a 2015 Ford Ranger XLT 3.2L PX Model (Diesel) (175,000kms)

It starts with my car driving just fine, until about a month ago, where I got an EGR Valve (Open/Stuck) code on my dash, with the car going into limp mode.

I disassembled the EGR Valve (Never done this before) and opened it to find it was COMPLETELY carbon'd. Cleaned it out, fixed it, reinstalled
(With the exception of 1 x Metal Gasket )

Turned car on, started driving, ENGINE LIGHT was gone.

Thought all was good.

Until, Day later, Was driving, Recognized the car had lost a lot of acceleration and power.

Also noticed smoke was billowing out the back under load and the RPM would flutter leading up to cruising speed (40kms/60kms)

Went back under the hood, reinspected.

Found the EGR Bypass was completely carboned as well, so figured, the whole intake was as well. Decided to remove the THROTTLE BODY, Where it meets the Manifold, THE WHOLE THINGS WAS CARBONED, I MEAN CARBONED.

Anyway, Cleaned it out, re-installed, realized there were many/several bolts loose on the EGR valve and the EGR area, Re-tightened everything down, CAR FELT LIKE IT WAS DRIVING MUCH BETTER, BUT NOT BACK TO NORMAL.

Still getting slight RPM flutters, still small amounts of black smoke coming out, still slight loss of power.

That's all I have to go by...

Does this sound and feel most likely like a vacuum leak ?

I have a OB 2 Scanner but im not sure what my Air Mass Flow Rate suppose to be?

My EGR command - error can fluctuate up to -40% but i figured this could be a delay in the EGR catching up ? Would this still mean it's sticking ? Should the value always be 0% ?

Comment: Which fuel does it use?

Comment: It runs on Diesel